# React Native Development Workflow

Tags: react-native, command-line-interface, workflow

Hi iam new to the field of react native app development and had completed course in udemy.

But which cli should I choose first and according to which circumstances I should choose specific cli ?

What should be the workflow while designing app from scratch and which all languages do I need to know inorder to make successful completion of app ?

Totally confused and need help and direction in this issue.